# Importing python module with absolute path throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

How to import a module with absolute path and pass parameter to that module so that the called module can actually use that variable inside it? By absolute path I mean something like this `"/home/example.com/directory/file.py"`. I get this module name as part of command line argument to my actual script. Inside that script I have to import `file.py` and pass certain arguments to them.
Ex Code:

```
    filename = '/home/example.com/directories/file.py'
    path = re.split(filename, script_path, maxsplit=1)[0]
    print(path) --> /home/example.py/directories/
    module_name = filename.rstrip('.py')
    print(module_name) --> file.py
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    print(type(module))
    # filepath = re.sub('/','.',script_path)
    # print(filepath)
    # module = importlib.import_module(script_path)
    module.testvars = [r_config, t_config]
    # spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    alltest = unittest.TestSuite()
    alltest.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module))
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
```

But I get the following error with this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```